# z-index issues in safari

Tags: html, css, firefox, safari, z-index

I am having some trouble with z-index working on a fixed element in safari. I created the scrolling site in firefox and wasn't even needing to specify z-index for the simple text div to be behind the other content until scrolled down to. But for some reason in Safari it shows up in front of everything else. I have tried creating a negative z-index for it and positive z-index for everything else but no change. Here is the code for it.

Thanks for any help!

Also here is the link to view it if that helps make more sense (you have to login to view the site - use username stackoverflow password:stackoverflow

http://lynchbryan.com/wp-login

```
<div id="tagline">
   <span class="tags">We</span><span class="tagl">partner</span> <span class="tags">with clients to</span> </br><span class="tagl">cultivate</span> <span class="tags">the</span> <span class="tagl">potential</span><span class="tags"> of people</span>
</div>
```

```css
#post-16 #tagline {
    position:fixed;
    bottom:50%;
    text-align: center;
    left: 50%;
    z-index:-999;
}

#post-16 .tags {
    font-family:'AndesLight';
    font-size:23px;
    color:#ffffff;
    padding:0 10px;
}

#post-16 .tagl {
    font-family:'ThirstyRoughReg';
    font-size:50px;
    color:#ffffff;
}
```

Comment: I know this doesn't answer your question but why not toggle display:none; display:< not none >; to show and hide it?

Comment: @JeffPowers - That could work. I am assuming that is done with Jquery? (which I don't really know much of)

Comment: I'll post it in an answer below.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't suggest trying to hide something with `z-index`.  Instead you should try `display: none;`.  If that's not the issue you're encountering then I still wouldn't suggest setting a negative `z-index` value.  It's good practice to keep these values at 0 or above.  Try setting the z-index of everything else to a higher number like 3 or 4 and then setting `#post-16 #tagline` to 1 or 2.

**EDIT**

According to your comments, you want to hide `.tags` and `.tagl`.  You should do the following CSS rule, ignoring the `z-index`:

```
.tags, .tagl { display: none; }
```

Comment: I don't know if I explained it well enough but .tags and .tagl are what I am trying to hide. I just edited above with the link so that you can view the site.

Comment: Look at my revised post on how to hide those classes.

Answer (score 0):

Based off of what you have already. A really simple example would be. You may want to throttle of often the scroll event is called since it will be called a lot.

```
#post-16 #tagline {
  position:fixed;
  bottom:50%;
  text-align: center;
  left: 50%;
  display: none;
}

//cache the element so you only need to look it up once.
var $tag = $('#post-16 #tagline');

//name space the scroll event
$(document).on('scroll.show-tagline' function (e) {
  //this is how far the document has been scrolled in pixels
  var scrolled = $(this).scrollTop();
  //what ever value you want
  if ( scrolled > 300 ) { 
    $tag.show();
  } else {
    $tag.hide();
  }
})
```